# Remove Cell Borders with an IF function

Tags: excel, vba

I've been doing some coding this past few days and I'm kinda stuck in this part. I want to clear the borders of the selected cells with an `IF` function. But it's not working. No errors and when I walk through in VB editeor, it's running perfectly fine. Need help. Please.

```
Range("G4:H4", Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

With Worksheets("Sort Tool").Range("G4:H4", Selection.End(xlDown))
    If Selection.Borders.LineStyle = xlContinous Then
        Selection.Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
    End If
End With
```

Comment: your _selections_ statements looks unclear: explain better what are you actually trying to accomplish

Comment: @user3598756: I'm trying to remove the borders on Cell G4 and H4 down but it's not all the time that it has a border. That's where the If statement comes in. That if the Selected Cells have borders, it will be removed.

Comment: `xlContinous ` should be  `xlContinuous`

Comment: @gizlmeier: I'm not sure why excel still accepted that syntax but it's not fixing it. It still skips the IF function. Thanks for pointing it out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
With Worksheets("Sort Tool").Range("G4:H4")
    Range(.Cells, .Cells.End(xlDown)).Borders.LineStyle = xlNone
End With
```

Comment: That code bypass the IF statement altogether. The range changes borders from time to time that's why an IF statement is added there. If the Range Border xlContinuous, to change it to xlNone.

Comment: so are there cells with border styles different from xlContinuous you want to keep?

Comment: No. Just to change xlContinuous to xlNone.

Comment: then try my code since it changes all borders to `xlNone`!

Comment: @Marco, did you try it?

Comment: I think I figured it out. Your code works. The main issue I was having was the cells I'm trying to clear are protected. Thanks for you code, great help!